# Strange git diff sometimes

Tags: git, diff

Sometimes before I commit, the diff gets weird. like in this case,
[image: example]
the line with `#pragma` had no change. I just added the new method above it. and for some reason this diff thinks that i deleted and rewritten that line.
How can I avoid this kind of behaviour? What is the reason for it?

Comment: What diff tool are you using? In my experience, the output can vary quite a bit between different tools. Also maybe you can provide an example? I tried to replicate the issue but at least with `git diff` I had no luck.

Comment: i use gitX (https://github.com/rowanj/gitx). otherwise i dont have anything about difftool in my config. do you recommend some other than the default one or gitx?

Answer (score 2):

Line 294 used to have

```
#pragma mark web editing
```

But now line 294 has

```
- (void)aNewMEthod
```

Because this line 294 now contains something that it did not earlier, the diff thinks you replaced it. And you did. *You* know you just moved it down a couple lines, but the diff just sees 2 different lines in the same place, hence it thinks you replaced it wholly.

Line 299 used to be blank, but it now has

```
#pragma mark web editing
```

Because it was blank before and something was put there (it being moved down due to the method insertion above) it thinks it's a newly added line, while really it was just moved.

That's what it does, it compares lines and reports where the old and new don't match.

You see the same sort of behaviour when you move files around in a git project. Git then thinks you deleted the file at place A, and created a new file with the same contents at place B.

This is how it works, you shouldn't want to avoid/change this behaviour,

Comment: so is there a way to make it more aware? like make it understand that i just moved a line up or down instead of knowing what a line has? im thinking that because if i have something on line 5, and then i add 3 new lines after line 2, it knows that i just added the 3 lines, and it doesnt highlight that i deleted line 5 and added it to line 8 or so.

Comment: Not that i know of. Perhaps there is a difftool that lets you customize the output, but i always use the default diff so i dont know. You can use `git difftool --tool-help` to get a list of difftools

Comment: @TimCastelijns What you explain in the answer is not generally true. Usually git recognizes the inserts and does no intermediate removals of identical lines. At least in my experience. Maybe it's a corner case here?

Comment: @musiKk This is what it has always done for me, i had never heard of anyone experiencing it differently (until i read your comment)

Comment: To be fair, I never heard anyone experiencing it at all because this is such a specialized topic. I just typed in the lines from the screenshot in the question. They appear as one added chunk, nothing else.